# Probability of Y students having the same test

Tags: probability

I have been sitting a test today in a class of 15, and two guys around me got the same version of the test as me. That got me wondering...

There are X versions of the test. What is the probability, that

a)  Exactly Y students

b)  At least Y students

c) What framework do you use when thinking about these (presumably) basic probability problems? I for the most part am trying to determine, if it's any of the variations, permutations, or combinations. But, if it's anything else than these I get stuck wondering, if I have to take into account order, position, etc.

from Z students will sit next to each other and have the same test version.

a) So the thought is that P of Y students having the same version of the test from X tests is $P=(\frac{1}{X})^{Y-1}$. The reason is that any of the Y students can get any of the X tests, and the Y-1 students need to have the same test.

Going from here, there is the same probability for any of the groups that can be created, sitting next to each other. There can be Z-Y+1 of these as shown by the diagram below.
[image]

The probability of three tests not being the same in any group is $P=1-(\frac{1}{X})^{Y-1}$. We have to do this for every one of the given groups, that is exponentiation.
So my guess would be, that the probability of exactly Y students sitting next to each other would be $$P=1-{\{[1-(\frac{1}{X})^{Y-1}]^{Z-Y+1}\}}$$
Am I even remotely close to the real way of solving these kinds of problems?

b)
There is the obvious one
$$ \sum_{n=Y}^{Z} P(n) $$
but are there any other, more elegant solutions that cross your mind?

P.S. If there is any way, in which I could improve, or generalize title, or content of my question to help other users, please let me know.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Im stating this answer as a permutations question

Assuming the class has $n$ people

$$
\begin{align}
P(\text{Y having same test})&={n(\text{Y having same test})\over n(\text{Total combinations})}\\
&={{n\choose Y}X(X-1)^{n-Y}\over X^n}={{n\choose Y}X\over (X-1)^Y}{\left({X-1\over X}\right)^n}
\end{align}
$$

Atleast Y is just addition of probabilities